# Java compare user input to char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

First off hello, new here. I'm fairly new to Java and I'm having some issues with comparing user input using the `Scanner` class to a dynamically created `char` array. I have a list of 10 words, program randomly choosing one, then converting that to a `char` array. I've got all that working. I'm having an issue comparing the user input to a `char` in the array. I'm basically practicing `String` manipulation and am creating a simple hang man game my daughter can fool with. Any advice would be appreciated, helpful links to some information would be great too. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] words = new String[10];

        words[0] = "Elsa";
        words[1] = "Anna";
        words[2] = "Olof";
        words[3] = "Sphen";
        words[4] = "Christoph";
        words[5] = "TinkerBell";
        words[6] = "Arial";
        words[7] = "SnowWhite";
        words[8] = "Cinderella";
        words[9] = "SleepingBeauty";

        Random selWord = new Random();
        int newWord = selWord.nextInt(10);

        char[] wordLetters = words[newWord].toCharArray();
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please make your first guess");

        for (int i=0; i < words[newWord].length(); i++) {
            System.out.print("_ ");
        }

        if (!userInput.hasNextLine()) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter letters only.");
            } while (!userInput.hasNext());
        }

        for (int n=0; n < wordLetters.length; n++) {
            String userChoice = userInput.nextLine();

            if (wordLetters[n] == userChoice.charAt(n)) {
                System.out.println("You've made a match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, try again.");
            }
        }

        userInput.close();

        // System.out.println(words[newWord]);
        // System.out.println(words[newWord].length());

    }
}
```

Comment: And the specific issue being?

Comment: Sorry, should have been a bit more clear. In the last for loop It simply does not compare the user input to the char array. even when set the code so I know what the word is and I enter a correct word, it just skips to the else statement and outputs Sorry, try again. Then it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You might want to print out both `wordLetters[n]` and `userChoice.charAt(n)` before the `if` condition to check what you get is what you were expecting. I would recommend using a debugger if you can.

Comment: I'm not sure you "String userChoice = userInput.nextLine();" inside your loop, but you will need a double loop (on within the other) so you can compare each character in the word with each character in the user input

Comment: Hi, I'm Olof, and I like worm hogs!

Comment: ok, I've printed out the char[] for the random word, its does indeed print the word. however, again it skips the first part of the if statement and just right to Sorry try again,  it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

`String userChoice = userInput.nextLine();
 ` char[] selection = userChoice.toCharArray();
 ` 
 ` for (int n=0; n < wordLetters.length; n++) {
  ` for (int k=0; k < selection.length; k++) {
    
  `  if (wordLetters[n] == userChoice.charAt(n)) {
  `   System.out.println("You've made a match");
   ` } else {
   `  System.out.println("Sorry, try again.");
   ` }
   `}
  `}

Comment: sorry can't get the code to print proper in the comment

Comment: @Dave please edit the code in the question itself so that it is readable. Also, check the answers and see if any of it solves your issue.

Comment: I haven't taken a close look at your code, but you dont need to compare the input to a char array in hangman. The input is just one character at a time (correct?) so simply loop through the contents of the char array storing the correct word or even use a string token storing the correct word and loop through the string contents using charAt() and compare the letter then match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are expecting the user to input a character at each line, but then you compare it with `userChoice.charAt(n)`. You should compare it with the character which will be at `userChoice.charAt(0)`.

Change this:

```
if (wordLetters[n] == userChoice.charAt(n))
```

To:

```
if (wordLetters[n] == userChoice.charAt(0))
```

In addition to this, I think your check below should be inside the `for` loop before you do `String userChoice = userInput.nextLine()`:

```
if (!userInput.hasNextLine()) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter letters only.");
        } while (!userInput.hasNext());
    }
```

---

So your `for` loop should look something like this:

```
for (int n=0; n < wordLetters.length; n++) {
        while (!userInput.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Please enter letters only.");
        }
        String userChoice = userInput.nextLine();

        if (wordLetters[n] == userChoice.charAt(0)) {
            System.out.println("You've made a match");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, try again.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changing `userChoice.charAt(n)` to `(0)` fixed the issue. Thanks everyone for the help. Now I need work work on compairing a single letter input against the char[] for matches.

Thanks again guys.

Comment: @Dave you can mark as an answer if you think this appropriately answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran you above code and it works.
I have put a System.out.println(newWord); to know what number has been randomly picked up and from the array if I type the same it says "You've made a match"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I read your code, seems it's totally unplayable.

so I made some change here

```
      String[] words = new String[10];

        words[0] = "Elsa";
        words[1] = "Anna";
        words[2] = "Olof";
        words[3] = "Sphen";
        words[4] = "Christoph";
        words[5] = "TinkerBell";
        words[6] = "Arial";
        words[7] = "SnowWhite";
        words[8] = "Cinderella";
        words[9] = "SleepingBeauty";

    Random selWord = new Random();
    int newWord = selWord.nextInt(10);

    char[] wordLetters  = words[newWord].toCharArray();
    boolean[] CheckBox  = new boolean[wordLetters.length];//check each letter is correct
    boolean checkRoundbyRound = false;//check the round have make matchs
    int correctWords=0;//count how many letter is matched
    for(int n=0;n< wordLetters.length; n++) CheckBox[n]=false;//initail
    Scanner userInput;

    System.out.println("Let's start");

    while(true)
    {               
        //initail 
        checkRoundbyRound=false;
        correctWords=0;

        //Hanging
        for (int n=0; n < words[newWord].length(); n++) 
        {
            if(CheckBox[n]) 
                System.out.print(wordLetters[n]+" ");
            else
                System.out.print("_ ");
        }

        System.out.println("\nPlease enter letters only.");
        userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userChoice = userInput.nextLine();

        for (int n=0; n < wordLetters.length; n++) 
        {
            for(int m=0;m<userChoice.length();m++)
            {   
                //remember change the case, just for case :D
                if (Character.toLowerCase(wordLetters[n]) == Character.toLowerCase(userChoice.charAt(m))) 
                {
                    CheckBox[n] = true;
                    checkRoundbyRound = true;
                } 
            }
        }

        //Check have make match this round
        if(checkRoundbyRound)
            System.out.println("You've made a match");
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, try again.");

        //count how many letters found
        for(int n=0;n<wordLetters.length;n++)
        {
            if(CheckBox[n])correctWords++;
        }

        //if all letters are correct, end game
        if(correctWords==wordLetters.length)
            break;
    }
```

wish your daughter have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your code is very helpful, I had thought about checking case but was going do that once I got it actually working for the complete word check. I hope she has fun too while I learn the language. Thanks again for your input.